# android, custom state_pressed doesn't work

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-custom-drawable

My custom selector like below doesn't work as expected, I don't see the **pressed** state at all. Any tip? thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    >
    <!-- this state button has special design:
        + enabled state has white text on green background
        + disabled state has grey text on greyer background
    -->


    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_primary"
        android:color="@color/white"

        />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_pressed"
        android:color="@color/white"

        />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_pressed"
        android:color="@color/white"

        />
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_flat"
        android:color="@color/grey_subtext"
        />

</selector>
```

Comment: linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042866/state-list-drawable-and-disabled-state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try moving state_pressed to top like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>
<!-- this state button has special design:
    + enabled state has white text on green background
    + disabled state has grey text on greyer background
-->

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_pressed"
    android:color="@color/white"

    />

<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_primary"
    android:color="@color/white"

    />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_pressed"
    android:color="@color/white"

    />
<item android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_flat"
    android:color="@color/grey_subtext"
    />
```

**Edit:**
As *@forcewill* mentioned, Just to note that the reason behind moving the pressed state to the top has to do with the fact that Android will use the first state that match, in your case the widget is enabled and pressed simultaneous so it was matching the enabled state first.

Comment: Just to note that the reason behind moving the pressed state to the top has to do with the fact that Android will use the first state that match, in your case the widget is enabled and pressed simultaneous so it was matching the enabled state first

Answer (score 2):

The selector XML tag always picks the **first** matching item. This means if the View is enabled it will always show `@drawable/cb_shape_button_primary`.  A general rule of thumb with selectors is that your "default" item should be the last one in the list.

Try moving your default state last and see if that resolves your issues.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    >
    <!-- this state button has special design:
        + enabled state has white text on green background
        + disabled state has grey text on greyer background
    -->

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_pressed"
        android:color="@color/white"

        />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_pressed"
        android:color="@color/white"

        />
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_flat"
        android:color="@color/grey_subtext"
        />

   <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cb_shape_button_primary"
        android:color="@color/white"

        />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/select_item" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unselect_item" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unselect_item" android:state_checked="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/select_item" android:state_checked="true" />
```

Comment: You should not just post code but also explain why you made your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

### For Simple Select And Unselect Use This

```
<selector><item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radiobtnunselected"/><item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radiobtnselected"/></selector>
```

And Set Your Image At android:drawable

### True: Selected

### False: Unselected