# Button change color

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-widget

I have two buttons in layout,let suppose button A and button B and I want that when user touch any of two button,their background color should change for that moment.

## code

``

```
<item android:state_hovered="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/state_hovered"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/state_pressed"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/state_deafult" />
```

``

State_pressed working...but state_hovered is not working.
So,please suggest a way to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share your code so anyone helps to solve your problem.

Comment: please google state list drawble in android

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042866/state-list-drawable-and-disabled-state

Answer (score 0):

Change color while button is pressed?

See an answer to this question, [asked previosly in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147824/how-do-i-set-a-different-color-for-the-pressed-state-of-the-button):

Create a `my_button_background.xml` file in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/gold" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

And use this in layout file:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_button_background"
```

And read more about [Android's Color State](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource). Basically, you can assign colors, drawables, shapes, etc. to different states of views, such as enabled, disabled, focused, clicked, etc.