# How can I have more than one imageview on the screen at the same time when I click the screen? (Circle one imageview)

Tags: java, android

Imageview wherever I touch on Android
I want to show. Can you help me?

In the article I wrote below, my project is how I want to use it.

You have to get screen pressure as we want from you, you should create a new component on the screen every time you click on the screen, you can do this on the java side, every component that is produced will appear and disappear on the screen for 1 second, you can use the timer, you can use the native animations of the android. In other words, what we want right now is to create a new circle with each click on the screen and to have more than one circle at the same time on the screen, and each will have its own start and end time, the components will be removed when the time is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use selector background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_normal" android:state_focused="true"/>
<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_normal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use state drawable on your image view. Set drawable what you want state_pressed="true" and state_pressed="false". This will do the magic what you want

[State list drawable and disabled state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042866/state-list-drawable-and-disabled-state)